# mixpanel track_links not tracking properly

Tags: jquery, mixpanel

I am using code like the following using mixpanel's javascript api:

```
$(function() {
mixpanel.track_links("a[href~='/posts/more']", "Show more posts.",
      { "topic_id": "<%= @topic.id.to_guid %>" });
});
```

It doesn't seem to work. I have tried the variation without the single quotes to no avail.

```
$(function() {
    mixpanel.track_links("a[href~=/posts/more]", "Show more posts.",
          { "topic_id": "<%= @topic.id.to_guid %>" });
});
```

Is there something wrong with the above code?

The following link is on the page:

```
<a href="/posts/more?i=20&id=0a5cb302-859e-11e1-8851-24c603d12b60&type=Topic" data-remote="true">Show More...</a>
```

When I click on it, no event is fired.

Comment: Is your selector correct? Do you get a result when you just try `$("a[href~=/posts/more]")`

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason you might be having is that richer selectors such as `a[href~=/posts/more]` aren't supported by the mixpanel lightweight selector engine.

From some quick testing I think only classes, id's and elements work.

I've emailed them regarding this, I would for example really need the ability to pass in a jQuery object as a selector but it's simply not possible as of now. (There used to be support apparently, maybe it will be back).

If you are after a temporary fix add a class and then pass that to the track_links function but I know, it's far from ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Vagni is correct, the Mixpanel JS library includes its own implementation of a basic CSS selector engine which is extremely limited.

You probably can't do attribute selection, or at least not substring matching attribute selection, and I know from debugging my own problems that child selectors plus classes (e.g. "p a.foo") doesn't work.

A better approach would be to use jQuery (or whatever you have on the page already, Rails will make jqlite available for you) to watch for the clicks you're interested in and track the Mixpanel events by hand.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href~=/posts/more]', function() { 
    mixpanel.track("Show more posts.", { "topic_id": "<%= @topic.id.to_guid %>" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel (and Google Analytics) uses AJAX calls to send the events to their servers, you can’t just redirect the page while an AJAX call is in progress or it will be cancelled. The information simply never reaches their servers, and the event won't get tracked.

Mixpanel recommends that you add a small timeout before redirecting so the AJAX call can be completed.

I found a workaround which uses cookies without adding the timeout, however it won't work in realtime. You can check it in the following link http://tech.matchfwd.com/tag/mixpanel/.

**Update:** I just found in the Mixpanel official documentation that the method `track_links` will do that for you. It will wait the 300ms before performing the redirect.

https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript-full-api#track_links